# How to find lead owner's manager's email using soql query

Tags: batch

For my batch job, I've written the following query, since i want a string for the email, since I need a string (which I'll convert to string array later) for the `setToAddresses` method of the `singleEmailMessage` :

```
String mgrEmail = [select Owner.manager.email from Lead].Owner.manager.email;
```

The error is:

> cannot understand relationship 'manager' in field path

How can I fix it?

List u = [select Owner.Id from Lead WHERE Owner.Type IN ('User')];

gives the following error :
Illegal assignment from list to list

Comment: As Owner can be a user or a Queue and so on, you cannot do this in one simple query.

Answer (score 4):

`Lead.Owner` is a polymorphic relationship between Lead and User. You need to tell your query that's the relationship between the two. See the documentation on [Working with Polymorphic Relationships in SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm). Your query should look more like the following:

```
list<User>Usr = [select Owner.Id from Lead WHERE Owner.Type IN ('User')];
```

You'll probable then need to run a separate query to get your manager Email

```
list<User>mgrUsrs = [Select manager.email FROM User where Id IN: Usr];

// use a for loop to extract the list of email addresses into list<string>mgremails
```

You shouldn't need a `WHERE manager.Type IN (User)` since Manager is a valid field of User, but you may since it's also a reference to a different `User`. I've never tried to get that field, so you'll have to try it for yourself.

If the owner can be a `Queue` in your org, you'll want to take that into account by changing the first query to `WHERE Owner.Type in (User, Queue)`, then adjust the 2nd query accordingly.

Comment: List <User> u = [select Owner.Id from Lead WHERE Owner.Type IN ('User')];

gives the following error : Illegal assignment from list to list

Comment: See edit above where I've applied LIMIT 1 clause and had query return 1 record. I don't know the context you're using this in, so you may want to bulkify it; in which case you'd want a `list<string>` of email addresses you'd get from your 2nd query.

Comment: Sir, this time for the first query, i got the following error : Illegal assignment from list to user. I'm trying to write a batch job that searches for leads that have not been modified in the current month. for all such leads, i want to send an email alert to the lead owner's manager

Comment: Since I don't know what your batch code looks like, I've bulkified the code to give you a list from the first query and used those results in the 2nd query. If that doesn't work, you may need to extract the Ids from the 1st query into a list for use in the 2nd query even though that's what gets returned from the 1st. You'll then need to extract the email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can use this SOQL syntax as Lead owner represents [**polymorphic relationships**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys) where Owner can be a Group or User. You would need to make use of "[**TYPEOF**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm)" clause in order to achieve your requirement.

```
[SELECT 
 TYPEOF Owner 
  WHEN USER THEN Owner.Manager.Email 
 END
 FROM Lead]
```

**Please note:**

> TYPEOF is currently available as a Developer Preview as part of the SOQL Polymorphism feature. For more information on enabling TYPEOF for your organization, contact Salesforce.

Comment: TypOf is in Developer Preview, but querying for Type is currently available.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I was thinking in lines of achieving using single query and hence suggested TypeOf.